# Adding a floating joint to a sphere in urdf

Tags: control, ros, simulation, joint

I am trying to create a sphere that I can control through pybullet. I have a basic urdf specification that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="0.0" ?>
<robot name="urdf_robot">
<link name="base_link">
  <contact>
    <rolling_friction value="0.005"/>
    <spinning_friction value="0.005"/>
  </contact>
  <inertial>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.17"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="textured_sphere_smooth.obj" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="white">
      <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <sphere radius="0.5"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
</robot>
```

But to control velocity instead of only external force I need add a joint. I tried adding a floating joint:

```
<joint name="control" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="internal_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5"/>
</joint>
<link name="internal_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01"/>
  </inertial>
</link>
```

but pybullet crashes when trying to load that without a helpful message. I don't know urdf well. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint type you've added to the `URDF` is `fixed` rather than the desired `floating`. Fortunately, `floating` is indeed a type of joint listed in the [`URDF` Joint spec](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#Attributes). I am not familiar with `pybullet` so I can't speak to whether this is the underlying issue with it crashing. It could also be an issue with the `XML` version being `0.0`; it needs to be at least `1.0`. As for your updated `URDF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="urdf_robot">
<joint name="control" type="floating">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="internal_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5"/>
</joint>
<link name="internal_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01"/>
  </inertial>
</link>
<link name="base_link">
  <contact>
    <rolling_friction value="0.005"/>
    <spinning_friction value="0.005"/>
  </contact>
  <inertial>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.17"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="textured_sphere_smooth.obj" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="white">
      <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <sphere radius="0.5"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
</robot>
```

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be an issue with bullet. https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/1148